# pg restore - where is the schema?

Tags: postgresql

I successfully restored a dump from Postgresql 11 into 9.3.9.

```
postgres=# drop database ambari
DROP DATABASE
[dumps]$ pg_restore -U postgres  -h db ambari.dump
-- Dumped from database version 11.7
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 11.7
-- Name: ambari; Type: SCHEMA; Schema: -; Owner: ambari
CREATE SCHEMA ambari;
ALTER SCHEMA ambari OWNER TO ambari;
SET default_tablespace = '';
-- Name: adminpermission; Type: TABLE; Schema: ambari; Owner: ambari
CREATE TABLE ambari.adminpermission (
  permission_id bigint NOT NULL,
  permission_name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  resource_type_id integer NOT NULL,
  permission_label character varying(255),
  principal_id bigint NOT NULL,
  sort_order smallint DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE ambari.adminpermission OWNER TO ambari;
```

etc

```
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
```

When I list the databases, there is no ambari even there was in the original database.

```
[dumps]$ psql -U postgres  -h db
postgres=# \l
                               List of databases
Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
jiradb7     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
postgres    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
template0   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
template1   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
```

I cannot find it between the schemas either:

```
postgres=# \dn
List of schemas
Name  |  Owner
public | postgres


postgres-# select nspname from pg_catalog.pg_namespace;
  nspname
pg_toast
pg_temp_1
pg_toast_temp_1
pg_catalog
public
information_schema
```

My question where the ambari schema is?

Update:

```
[dumps]$ psql -U postgres  -h db
psql (11.7, server 9.3.9)
postgres=# create database ambari;
CREATE DATABASE
[dumps]$ pg_restore -U postgres  -h db -d ambari ambari.dump
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while INITIALIZING:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout"
Command was: SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "row_security"
Command was: SET row_security = off;
WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 2

postgres=# \l
                               List of databases
Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
ambari      | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
(7 rows)

postgres=# \c ambari
psql (9.2.24, server 9.3.9)
You are now connected to database "ambari" as user "postgres".
ambari=# \d
No relations found.
ambari=# \dtvs ambari.*
                List of relations
Schema |             Name              | Type  | Owner
ambari | adminpermission               | table | ambari
ambari | adminprincipal                | table | ambari
ambari | adminprincipaltype            | table | ambari
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't restore the dump. Your `pg_restore` invocation output the contents of the dump to standard output. To restore the dump into a database, you have to add the `-d` option:

```
pg_restore -U postgres -h db -d databasename ambari.dump
```

The second attempt seems to have succeeded. You probably don't see the tables because they are not on your `search_path`. Try `\dt *.*`.

Comment: Thanks, then the output is quite confusing. So I created the ambari database and repeated with that parameter. When I want to list the objects, it says no relations:
postgres=# \c ambari
You are now connected to database "ambari" as user "postgres".
ambari=# \d
No relations found.

Comment: You should ask a new question for that and include your exact command and its output, including errors.

Comment: I have updated my question with new findings. I think that new question is not good idea - I just want to make sure that the restore worked.

Comment: Probably the tables are not on your `search_path`, see my updated answer.